# How to add Google Play application link to an application?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, uri

I have published an app and now I want to update it . I am trying to add a button to direct the users to my another app on Google Play. I will suggest my users to download my another app if they like the current one. I found this code and added to my code in onCreate method.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://HTTPS://details?id=com.example.android"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
```

I wrote the xml part and button definiton too. There is nothing wrong with them.
 I wrote my application's package name instead of com.example.android. Emulator crashes because there is no Googleplay in it. I tried this on my android device. It crashes too and I don't have any logcat for this. Can you suggest any other methods to give market link to my users ?(It should Directly open my application on google play , it should not visit the website)

P.S : I edited the code and it works. Here in case if anyone needs it.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });
```

Comment: after you edit your question,is it working now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
  startActivity(intent);
```